# iOS table disappears

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, searchbar

I have a `View Controller` that have a `tableView` inside it which has different data in it . when inside the search bar I search for a data in the table, it remove other data and just show the data i was looking for. when i click on the data it push to next view. Everything looks fine but when I go back to the view the tableview will be disappears ! The funny thing in the same app I have other similar view with similar code, but it's ok over there. anyone knows whats wrong with it ?!

Comment: check you -(void)viewWillAppear and -(void)viewDidDisAppear

Comment: lol it's gonna be a long code , but ok wait haha

Comment: I'm not using them in my code spider1983, what should i have in them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` i added `[mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];` which is my searchbar's textfield and it's ok now , thanks for answers guys

Comment: Mark your answer as solution.

Comment: ok i will but it says after 2 days i can accept my own answer :)